# Using LINQ on XML data source

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML collection so defined:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.example.com/Modules";
XNamespace ns2 = "http://www.example.com/Modules/Ext";


XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                    new XElement(ns + "Modules",
                        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "ns2", ns2 ),
                        new XElement(ns + "Module", "Introduction to LINQ"),
                        new XElement(ns + "Module", "LINQ and C#"),
                        new XElement(ns2 + "Extra", "Extra contect"))
    );
```

I would like to print the values for the "Module" elements. Here's my code:

```
var courses = from e in doc.Descendants("Module")
                let lowname = e.Value.ToLowerInvariant()
                where lowname.Contains("linq")
                orderby e.Value
                select e.Value;

foreach (var course in courses)
{
    Console.WriteLine(course);
}
```

I don't understand why I can't retrieve any data. Is the query wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify *namespace* when you are getting items as well.

```
XNamespace ns = "http://www.example.com/Modules";

var courses = from e in doc.Descendants(ns + "Module")
            let lowname = e.Value.ToLowerInvariant()
            where lowname.Contains("linq")
            orderby e.Value
            select e.Value;
```